# XOAUTH GMAIL Issues

Tags: oauth, gmail-imap

I have now tried a basic java implementation of a code for XOAUTH and Gmail, and I keep encountering into the popular "Invalid Credential Error". Is there a known solution to this as I cannot seem to find anything online. Please see below for my code:

CODE:

```
public class Oauth {

private static final String SCOPE = "https://mail.google.com/";

private static final String CONSUMER_KEY = "anonymous";
private static final String CONSUMER_SECRET = " anonymous ";
private static final String USER_EMAIL = "useremail@gmail.com";

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    GoogleOAuthParameters oauthParameters = new GoogleOAuthParameters();
    oauthParameters.setOAuthConsumerKey(CONSUMER_KEY);

    oauthParameters.setOAuthConsumerSecret(CONSUMER_SECRET);
    OAuthSigner signer = new OAuthHmacSha1Signer();

    GoogleOAuthHelper oauthHelper = new GoogleOAuthHelper(signer);

    oauthParameters.setScope(SCOPE);

    oauthHelper.getUnauthorizedRequestToken(oauthParameters);

    String requestUrl = oauthHelper.createUserAuthorizationUrl(oauthParameters);
    System.out.println(requestUrl);
    System.out.println("Please visit the URL above to authorize your OAuth "
            + "request token.  Once that is complete, press any key to "
            + "continue...");
    System.in.read();

    String token = oauthHelper.getAccessToken(oauthParameters);
    System.out.println("OAuth Access Token: " + token);
    System.out.println();

    //IMAP
    XoauthAuthenticator.initialize();

    IMAPSSLStore imapSslStore = XoauthAuthenticator.connectToImap("imap.googlemail.com   ",
            993,
            USER_EMAIL,
            oauthParameters.getOAuthToken(),
            oauthParameters.getOAuthTokenSecret(),
            new OAuthConsumer(null, CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, null),
            true);
    System.out.println("Successfully authenticated to IMAP.\n");
}

}
```

Please advise on your thought, and also be aware that I have tried using a real consumer key and secret with the same error, see below for exception:

ERROR:

> A1 NO [ALERT] Invalid credentials (Failure) Exception in thread "main"
>   javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: [ALERT] Invalid credentials
>   (Failure)   at
>   com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:660)     at
>   javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:295)    at
>   GMAILP.XoauthAuthenticator.connectToImap(XoauthAuthenticator.java:106)
>       at com.google.code.samples.xoauth.Oauth.main(Oauth.java:49)

The class Oauth was used with the other standard classes XoauthAuthenticator.java, XoauthProtocol.java, etc within the same package as seen in the [java sample zip](http://code.google.com/p/google-mail-xoauth-tools/downloads/list)

Please can you advise on this exception I'm facing as its looking like the Gmail Oauth protocol is looking more difficult than I expected, I just want to programmatically connect to a user's
email (following authorization) and retrieve email for further analysis, and I decided to use to use Gmail due to its open platform.

I deally I looking to implement a java equivalent of the xoauth.py file ([See this](http://code.google.com/p/google-mail-xoauth-tools/wiki/XoauthDotPyRunThrough)) as I have no knowledge of python, please advise on your thought.

Kind Regards,

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same problem and then made sure that the exchange with gmail was exactly as shown in [this example](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/gmail/oauth_protocol#imap_protocol_exchange)

i.e. sending a capability request to the server and also using exactly the same tags (e.g. A01) and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Add `Thread.Sleep(3000)` after `getFolder("Inbox");` and `inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);`

After doing this it is working for me.